# Spring Roo with Dojo/Dijit declative menu bar?

Tags: dojo, spring-roo

I am trying to use the [Dojo/Dijit declarative menu](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dijit/MenuBar.html) with Spring ROO 1.1.4, but even if I replace the complete roo generated menue.jspx with the example (ligthly addapted) from the Dojo/Dijit hompage, it does not replace the decorated menu divs with the menu.

that is how it look

[image: how it look]

that is how should look:

[image: how shoul look]

My modified menu.jspx

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<jsp:root xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page"
    xmlns:menu="urn:jsptagdir:/WEB-INF/tags/menu"
    xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags" 
    version="2.0">
    <jsp:directive.page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
    <jsp:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" />

    <script type="text/javascript">
            dojo.require("dijit.MenuBar");
            dojo.require("dijit.PopupMenuBarItem");
            dojo.require("dijit.Menu");
            dojo.require("dijit.MenuItem");
            dojo.require("dijit.PopupMenuItem");
        </script>   
    </head>

        <div dojoType="dijit.MenuBar" id="navMenu">
            <div dojoType="dijit.PopupMenuBarItem">
                <span>
                    File
                </span>
                <div dojoType="dijit.Menu" id="fileMenu">
                    <div dojoType="dijit.MenuItem" onClick="alert('file 1')">
                        File #1
                    </div>
                    <div dojoType="dijit.MenuItem" onClick="alert('file 2')">
                        File #2
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div dojoType="dijit.PopupMenuBarItem">
                <span>
                    Edit
                </span>
                <div dojoType="dijit.Menu" id="editMenu">
                    <div dojoType="dijit.MenuItem" onClick="alert('edit 1')">
                        Edit #1
                    </div>
                    <div dojoType="dijit.MenuItem" onClick="alert('edit 2')">
                        Edit #2
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</jsp:root>
```

Can anybody give me a hint what I am doing wrong?
*(I know the fallback to do the menu programmatic, but I want to do it declarative.)*

---

The html header is looks like that:

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />    

    ...
    <script type="text/javascript">var djConfig = {parseOnLoad: false, isDebug: false, locale: '${fn:toLowerCase(userLocale)}'};</script>

    <script src="${dojo_url}" type="text/javascript"><!-- required for FF3 and Opera --></script>
    <script src="${spring_url}" type="text/javascript"><!-- /required for FF3 and Opera --></script>
    <script src="${spring_dojo_url}" type="text/javascript"><!-- required for FF3 and Opera --></script>
    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">dojo.require("dojo.parser");</script>      


    <spring:message code="application_name" var="app_name"/>
    <title><spring:message code="welcome_h3" arguments="${app_name}" /></title>
</head>
```

Comment: Where are you including the dojo script tag? When is Dojo supposed to parse this?

Comment: @missingno: I have added the html header, is that what you want to know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't knows anything about Spring Roo, so maybe I'm saying something very stupid here...

Is that menu.jspx compiling into some static html? If this is the case, you can tell Dojo to parse your initial page simply by setting parseOnLoad to true on your djConfig

```
var djConfig = {parseOnLoad: true, ...}
```

(no need to require dojo.parser in this case).

On the other hand, if that template is inserted dinamicaly, you will need to call dojo.parser.parse() on the root 'navMenu' node yourself. You seem to be require-ing it, but I don't see where it is being called.

Comment: I will give them a try - Btw: It works in a static way: the menu.jspx and some ohter jspx files is a file are renderd and put together with Apache Tiles, then all is send to the Browser in one static file

Comment: the hint with parseOnLoad was great: I will acceept your answer, but please add the some phrase to make clear that one need to change the setting of line '<script type="text/javascript">var djConfig = {parseOnLoad: true, isDebug: false, ...};</script>' in file `load-script.tagx` to `parseOnLoad: true`  !

Answer (score 0):

I had to use:
{
dojo.addOnLoad(function(){
 dojo.parser.parse();
});
}

instead of parseOnLoad:true